# 'Await outside function error' syntax error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a general purpose discord bot and for one of the features I'm adding an 8ball minigame, but upon executing the following code i get the following error:

```py
 File "main.py", line 41
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

How can I solve this? Code attached below

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
    async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
      responses = [
    'It is certain',
    'It is decidedly so',
    'Without a doubt',
    'Yes, definitely',
    'You may rely on it',
    'As I see it, yes',
    'Most likely',
    'Yes',
    'Signs point to yes',
    'Reply hazy try again',
    'Ask again later',
    'Better not tell you now',
    'Cannot predict now',
    'Concentrate and ask again',
    'Dont count on it',
    'My reply is no',
    'My sources say no',
    'Outlook not so good',
    'Very doubtful'
    ]
    embed=discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="Question", value="{question}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Answer", value="{random.choice(responses)}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Looks like an indentation error.  `async def` should not be indented.

Comment: Please check the indentation of your real code.

Comment: @KyleParsons I'm not identing it?

Comment: @quamrana I have, but it's not indented.

Comment: Well, if we pasted the code as shown into a program there would be indentation problems.

Comment: The contents of the list display don't have to be indented. Ignoring the dedented decorator, the indentation isn't technically incorrect. But everything starting with `embed=...` occurs *after* the function definition; the indent level is not established by the `]`.

Comment: @chepner could you elaborate? I don't think I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Just an observation that even though `responses = [` is sufficiently indented to be part of the function definition, the strings inside the `[...]` don't need to be indented at all, as those lines are all continuations of the logical line started by the assignment. But when `embed=discord.Embed()` is encoutered, its indentation matches the indentation of the `async def` line, so it is not part of the definition; it *follows* the definition. That means `await ctx.send` follows the definition as well, and is not part of the definition. So, in short: check your indentation.

Comment: @chepner I have checked the indentation on both parts. Could you possibly provide a code snippet?

Comment: Sure. Look at your question. The last four lines of code *are not* part of the function definition, because they are not indented more than the `async def` line. If the code in your question does not match the code you are executing, please fix the question.

Comment: @chepner Thank you so much! That fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Asynchronous functions can only be awaited inside asynchronous functions. Either you tried to do the opposite or you made a mistake with indentation.

Comment: It is an asynchronous function (I believe), and I have gotten multiple comments about the identation even though it's not idented.

Comment: @MadeByAlvaropop What isn't indented?

Comment: The 'asnyc def' line, as some people commented.

Comment: The `async def` looks indented to me. What do you think the previous line is doing?

Comment: @quamrana Right. You can't have a decorator that isn't lined up with its function indent-wise.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your decorator is correctly indented, and you real code looks like this:

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
  responses = [
'It is certain',
...
]
embed=discord.Embed()
embed.add_field(name="Question", value="{question}", inline=False)
embed.add_field(name="Answer", value="{random.choice(responses)}", inline=False)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Strictly speaking, this indentation is fine. You have a function definition that consists of *one* line of code, the assignment to `responses`. The requirement is that each *logical* line be indented more than the `async def` line itself, but the implicit line continuation performed by `[...]` mean that the assignment is a single logical line spread over multiple physical lines. (More specifically, the first line of the body establishes the amount of indentation required by each following line.)

However, the indentation required for next line of code is not changed by the position of the `]`; you still need to indent a line of code by 2 spaces to be considered to have the same indentation level as the `responses = ...` line. That's not the case here: `embed=discored.Embed()` is *not* indented, so it *follows* the function definition, as do the next 3 lines. That means that `await ctx.send(embed=embed)`, though clearly *intended* to be part of the function given its use of one of the arguments, actually *follows* the definition, leading to the syntax error on `await` occurring outside a function.

The correct indentation would look like this (although I'm preserving the indentation of the list itself to show the contrast):

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
  responses = [
'It is certain',
...
]
  embed=discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name="Question", value="{question}", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Answer", value="{random.choice(responses)}", inline=False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

A more readable, idiomatic indentation scheme would be

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = [
      'It is certain',
      ...
    ]
    embed=discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="Question", value="{question}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Answer", value="{random.choice(responses)}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copying and pasting to demonstrate what the indentation should be.

Note how `async def` has no indentation here but in your code it's indented 4 spaces.  Also `responses` is indented 4 spaces instead of 6 and its indentation matches the indentation of the following code *including* the `await`.

In your code `async def` and `await` are both indented 4 spaces which means that `await` is not inside the `async def` thus the `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function` error.

```
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = [
        'It is certain',
        'It is decidedly so',
        ...,
        'Very doubtful',
    ]
    embed=discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name="Question", value="{question}", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Answer", value="{random.choice(responses)}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

As others noted, the indentation on the `responses` list is a bit freer, but I indented it in a conventional manner.